# ldap_error 81, Server connection lost

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, opendj

I have deployed OpenDJ application on one of the instances and written a java based application as well to access user details from OpenDJ using unbound LDAP SDK. All the things are up and running and working as well.

The issue occurs when the concurrent request for search user hit the OpenDJ and I get the exception as:

> Error while checking the user abdulwaheed in LDAP: Error code 81,
>   message LDAPSearchException(resultCode=81 (server down), numEntries=0,
>   numReferences=0, errorMessage='The connection to server
>   rfhat-iam-opendj.net:1389 was closed while waiting for a response to
>   search request SearchRequest(baseDN='uid=abdulwaheed
>   ,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com', scope=BASE, deref=NEVER, sizeLimit=1,
>   timeLimit=0, filter='(objectClass=*)', attrs={}).')

Previously, I thought the issue can be with my java application which is not able to handle multiple concurrent requests and not able to get any free connection but after looking into error code, the error is coming from OpenDj (LDAP_ERROR 81).

I looked into the OpenDJ connection as well and seems like all the config are set to its default value (unlimited).

So, I am not sure what can be the issue and where I can look into it further?

Comment: Check OpenDJ access logs to verify whether the request is received by the server or not. And if there is additional information.

Comment: I have checked the log of OpenDJ and there is no error register into the log file.

Comment: I there is no error registered in the log file (and no request), then it is a client side error. AFAIK, the OpenDJ server never returns an error 81 to a client application.